# Corrupt quotes in generated HTML for an ASPX

Tags: asp.net

intro: I am pretty sure this is my fault. But I just don't see it and before tearing my hair out, I thought I should ask here ;)

I have a button which looks like this in my ASPX:

```
<input onClick="ELB_ClearSelection('DropDownList___00178');"
type="Button" value="Clear" />
```

The HTML that is generated says:

```
<input onClick="ELB_ClearSelection("DropDownList___00178");"
type="Button" value="Clear" />
```

...which obviously does not work :(

I ran the thing through HTML Validator and apart from the 'usual' complaints (related to it not fully 'understanding' ASPX) I did not see anything special, I have progrrammatically checked for balanced quotes and did not see anything suspicious, so I have no ideas where to look further :(

In case it helps, here is the full ASPX:

```
<%@ Register tagPrefix="des" assembly="PeterBlum.DES" namespace="PeterBlum.DES" %>
<%@ Register tagPrefix="despval" assembly="PeterBlum.DES.NativeToDES" namespace="PeterBlum.DES.NativeToDES" %>
<%@Page Language="apl" Debug="true" Inherits="COPA" src="COPA_MS.dws" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="mbcbb" Namespace="MetaBuilders.WebControls" Assembly="MetaBuilders.WebControls.ComboBox" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ELB" Namespace="ELB" Assembly="EasyListBox" %>
<html><head>
    <meta name="date"      content="2009-01-03T10:55:39" />
    <meta name="generator" content="COPA_MS.DWS" defs="(11)(13)(14)" />
    <meta name="publisher" content="Dynamic Logistics Systems GmbH" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
    <title>
      COPA_MS  - Dispogruppen
      </title>   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./copa.css" />   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="custom-form-elements.js"></script>
    </head><body>
    <h1>
      <span class="copa">COPA-</span><span class="ms">MS:</span> Dispogruppen
      </h1>
    <form runat=server><des:PageSecurityValidator id="PageSecurityValidator1" runat="server" >
        </des:PageSecurityValidator>

      <input runat="server" type="hidden" NAME="SelMaskeId" value="11" ID=SelMaskeID>
        <input runat="server" type="hidden" NAME="TreffId" value="13" ID=TreffID>
          <table>
            <tr>
              <td valign="top"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label__________00176" Text="Code Dispogruppe" /> </td><td><elb:EasyListBox runat="server" ID="ComboBox_______00176"  Text="" MaxLength="6" Width="100"   SelectQuery="***" ConnectionStringSqlServer="xxx"  DataValueField="code" DataTextField="code" DisplayMode="Combo" LimitToList="false" ></elb:EasyListBox></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td valign="top"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label__________00177" Text="Bezeichnung" /> </td><td><elb:EasyListBox runat="server" ID="ComboBox_______00177"  Text="" MaxLength="50" Width="210"  SelectQuery="***" ConnectionStringSqlServer="xxx"  DataValueField="bez" DataTextField="bez" DisplayMode="Combo" LimitToList="false" ></elb:EasyListBox></td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td valign="top"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label__________00178" Text="Lieferant" /> </td><td><elb:EasyListBox runat="server" ID="DropDownList___00178"  Text="" MaxLength="0" Width="210" SelectQuery="***" ConnectionStringSqlServer="xxx"  DataValueField="id" DataTextField="bez"></elb:EasyListBox>
                 <input type="Button" value='Auswahl entfernen' onClick='ELB_ClearSelection("DropDownList___00178");' />
               </td>
              </tr><tr>
              <td valign="top"><asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label__________00182" Text="Dispo-Verfahren" /> </td><td><elb:EasyListBox runat="server" ID="DropDownList___00182"  Text="" MaxLength="0" Width="280       " Tref_Width="280" Tref_MaxLength="200" s_left="" s_top="" s_position="" css_sl="" css_tl="" css_dt=""  SelectQuery="***" ConnectionStringSqlServer="xxx"  DataValueField="id" DataTextField="bez"></elb:EasyListBox>
                  <input type="Button" value="Auswahl entfernen" onClick="ELB_ClearSelection('DropDownList___00182');" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table><br /><br />
          <asp:Button runat="server" ID="Button_Suchen"  Text="Suchen"  onClick="CatchAll_onClick" />

          </form>
        </body>
      </html>
```

Comment: It's probably nothing, but have you noticed that while you have two input elements with calls to ELB_ClearSelection, they're both different?  The first has onClick='ELB_ClearSelection("DropDownList___00178");', while the second has onClick="ELB_ClearSelection('DropDownList___00182');". Do both fail?

Comment: Whoa! Are you listening to what OJ is saying? Don't leave out your SA password in you markup. Do you want to make it into CodingHorror or WTF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
onClick='ELB_ClearSelection("DropDownList___00178")'
```

To this:

```
onClick="ELB_ClearSelection('DropDownList___00178')"
```

In your ASPX.

I'll avoid commenting on having select queries and login information for your DB in your markup!

Comment: Crap.  Beat me to it.  I think that's your problem.  The first <input> control has its quotes mixed up.

Comment: Yeah, hard to get an answer in quickly on here eh? :) Cheers for the backup!

Comment: LOL at that kind of avoidance.

Comment: I won't avoid commenting on it. Are you actually *trying* to get this code featured on thedailywtf.com? Change.... that.... immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally changed this little input to asp:Button which behaves better. Seems it's not a good idea to mix HTML-Controls and ASP-Controls. 
Anyway, thanks for your help, I learned a lot more than that. Embarrassing lesson, as expected ;)  :(